# How to change default notification in Android 8.1 and later

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've noticed that in Android 8.1 and later the system started adding notifications about running applications automatically.

[image]

The default "tap" action will take a user to "App Info", where the user can e.g. force the app to exit.

I want to change this behavior, remove the default, and add a couple of actions like:

1. Go to app
2. Exit the app completely (... and remove this notification from the tray)

Is there any good code sample for that? I did read the Google API docs about NotificationListener and Notification API's, but still am not sure how I can change the default behavior.

Should I do it in NotificationPosted event, or is there other way of doing this?

Comment: "the system started adding notifications about running applications automatically" -- not for every app. Otherwise, you'd have dozens of notifications. You are doing something in the background (foreground service?) that is triggering this notification to appear.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, you're right, I do have services in my app, but it doesn't change my qs

Comment: Well, then, you might start by identifying the particular behavior that you are doing that is triggering the notification. From there, you might identify alternatives to that behavior that either avoid the notification or give you control over its contents.

Comment: Particular behavior - services running within the app. I'm not aware about any alternatives to change that behavior. Are you saying that modifying the defaults for that notification is not possible?